# Invalid token when trying to login into Jupyter notebook with Docker jupyter/tensorflow-notebook

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I pulled a (seemingly popular, supported by Jupyter) jupyter-tensorflow Docker image using

`docker pull jupyter/tensorflow-notebook`

and started it successfully with

`docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/tensorflow-notebook`

However, upon navigating to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=177a....`, I am prompted for a password or token (despite the token already being present in the URL). 
I know of no password to use, and the token 177a... does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: jupyter prints the token right after launch. Can you attach to the container and see if it is there?

Comment: The token was there, the problem was that the notebook was not broadcasting where I thought it was (8888), because of a notebook that was still running I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite easy: there was an other Jupyter notebook server I wasn't aware of running. Closing it did the trick.

Comment: Made the same mistake as well. A simple `pgrep jupyter` showed I had another running instance.